# Regex - Most efficient expression for matching after start of line OR after specific character

Tags: regex, performance

I am trying to find the most efficient way to match characters after the start of the line OR after another character.

**Match criteria**

`ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]` - Matches from this need to be found immediately after `^`, or after `[-_.]`

Note: I am not 100% sure which flavour of regex the processor uses, but it doesn't seem to support non-capturing groups.

**Scenario:**

User tries to access a domain which is then checked against several regex expressions (including this example). If no match is found, access is permitted.

**Sample user inputs (to be blocked):**

```
ad.dailymail.co.uk
asdsa.adasdsa.dasdasd.asdasdasd.dasdasdsa.ad.test.com
```

**Regex tests:**

**ad.dailymail.co.uk**

- `(^|[-_.])ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]` - 13 steps
- `^(.*[-_.])?ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]` - 36 steps
- `^([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?[-_.])*ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]` - 69 steps

**asdsa.adasdsa.dasdasd.asdasdasd.dasdasdsa.ad.test.com**

- `(^|[-_.])ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]` - 151 steps
- `^(.*[-_.])?ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]` - 28 steps
- `^([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?[-_.])*ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]` - 86 steps

So far, it's looking as if `^(.*[-_.])?ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]` is most efficient, but is there another way to check that may be faster?

Also, can anybody tell my why`(^|[-_.])` consumes so many more steps than the other expressions?

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges, `(^|[-_.])ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]` is not equal to `^(.*[-_.])?ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]` and `^([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?[-_.])*ad([sxv])?[0-9]*[-_.]`. Are you only looking for a single match in each string? Or multiple?

Comment: I know they are not necessarily equal, but I am just trying to find the best method that will return a true or false to the match criteria. Only a single match in each - One of the two possibilities.

Comment: Ok, but note that most probably your tests are not valid since at regex101 you are using `g` modifier, and it might not be used in the actual app. Do not use regex101 to test real performance, you need to test it in the target environment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew noted, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the second regex to use a `??` modifier for the first group. So it will be lazy and stop at 0 times if you already find "ad..." at the beginning.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CdFUOw/1)**

It has even less steps than the first regexp (which was the fastest) (9 vs 10 steps)

The downside is that it **may** get a little worse (0-2 extra steps) for any "not starting by ad" urls. It will also depend if it matches or not. If it does not match, both regexes have same steps. If they match, It may have 1-2 extra steps.

You may do your maths and compute the number of urls of such types and decide according to the probability

Finally, I made a table withh all the results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and for going the extra mile with the table. How does the lazy quantifier work on an optional group? I understand it in the context of shortening a greedy match, but I can't quite wrap my head around how it changes the matching process in this scenario.

Comment: Actually, I wonder whether something like `\bad[sxv]?[0-9]*\b[-_.]` could even be suitable?

Comment: `\bad[sxv]?[0-9]*\b[-_.]` seems to be a lightly optimized version of Regex1. It behabes the same way. About lazy `?`: consider the string `ab` and the regexp `a??`: It will match: `nothing`, `a`, `nothing`, `nothing`. However, the regex `a??b` will just match `ab` because the extra b at the end forces the lazy `?` to match `a` 1 time. When a lazy `?` is found, 0 to 1 occurrences are possible (with 0 preferred). So if the only option to match is to find 1 occurrence, it will be matched if 0 does not match. See https://regex101.com/r/PxnBYB/4 and https://regex101.com/r/PxnBYB/5